RecurrenceTable - Message text not found
According to Mathematica documentation the following code works:
RecurrenceTable[{s1[n, k] == s1[n - 1, k - 1] - (n - 1) s1[n - 1, k], s1[0, k] ==KroneckerDelta[k]}, s1, {n, 0, 6}, {k, 0, 4}]

But my following code returns the message: "Message text not found". What is wrong in my code?:
RecurrenceTable[{s1[n, k] == k*s1[n - 1, k] + s1[n - 1, k - 1], s1[n, n] == s1[n, 0] == 1}, s1, {n, 0, 6}, {k, 0, 4}]


Clear the Kernel ?

I did. Doesn't help

Which version of Mathematica are you using? In v14.1, I get an error message RecurrenceTable::conarg: The arguments should be ordered consistently. It complains because of your s1[n, n] term.

I am using 12.1.1. What is wrong with the s1{n,n] Term?

tl;dr: The problem is the definition of $s_{1}$. For some arguments, $s_{1}$ is not defined, causing an infinitely long recursion loop.
Let's look at the following code:
s1[n_, k_] := k * s1[n - 1, k] + s1[n - 1, k - 1];
s1[n_, 0] := 1; s1[n_, n_] := 1;
Table[s1[n, k], {n, 0, 6}, {k, 0, 4}]
(*
   {{1, TerminatedEvaluation["RecursionLimit"], TerminatedEvaluation["RecursionLimit"], 
   TerminatedEvaluation["RecursionLimit"]}, {2, 1, TerminatedEvaluation["RecursionLimit"], 
   TerminatedEvaluation["RecursionLimit"]}, {3, 4, 1, TerminatedEvaluation["RecursionLimit"]},
   {4, 11, 7, 1}, {5, 26, 32, 11}, {6, 57, 122, 76}}
*)

You will get the error message $RecursionLimit: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded. ($3$ times) and General::stop: Further output of $RecursionLimit::reclim will be suppressed during this calculation.. So the problem probably lies in the definition of the recursive sequence.
In my experience, this mainly occurs when function values ​​cannot be calculated from the given data or when the code is too complex (which does not seem to be the case here). So let's try finding $s_{1}\left( 0,\, 1 \right)$ (for example):
\begin{align*}
s_{1}\left( n,\, k \right) &= k \cdot s_{1}\left( n - 1,\, k \right) + s_{1}\left( n - 1,\, k - 1 \right)\\
s_{1}\left( 0,\, 1 \right) &= 1 \cdot s_{1}\left( -1,\, 1 \right) + s_{1}\left( -1,\, 0 \right) = s_{1}\left( -1,\, 1 \right) + s_{1}\left( -1,\, 0 \right) = \overbrace{s_{1}\left( -1,\, 1 \right)}^{?} + 1\\
&= s_{1}\left( -2,\, 1 \right) + 2 = s_{1}\left( -3,\, 1 \right) + 3 = \ldots = s_{1}\left( -n,\, 1 \right) + n \tag{for $n \in \mathbb{N}$}\\
\end{align*}
aka since we don't know any $s_{1}\left( -n,\, 1 \right)$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ it's not defined aka it causing an infinitely long recursion loop which gives you an error. You can do this for more arguments and get the same result. E.g. You have the same problem for all $s_{1}\left( 0,\, k \right)$ and $k \notin \mathbb{Z}_{\leq 0}$.

Yes, I see. But now lets change limits in your example as follows:
s1[n_, k_] := k*s1[n - 1, k] + s1[n - 1, k - 1]; s1[n_, 0] := 1; s1[n_, n_] := 1; Table[s1[n, k], {n, 2, 6}, {k, 0, n}]
Then everything is fine but my changed code still shows the same problem:
RecurrenceTable[{s1[n, k] == s1[-1 + n, -1 + k] + k s1[-1 + n, k],    s1[n, n] == 1, s1[n, 0] == 1}, s1, {n, 2, 6}, {k, 0, n}] What do I miss this time?
